# google play developer console блокирует карты

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Создал Android-приложение с картами. При его запуске на эмуляторах и телефоне все работает отлично, карты отображаются. Но после публикации приложения как альфа-версии в google play developer console карты не могут нормально прогрузиться, в левом нижнем углу появляется значок google и на этом карты подвисают.

Comment: вам надо получить SHA1  hash от вашего ключа, которым подписывали  билд для google-play, а не от дебажного

Comment: как получите, просто его можете добавить уже к существующему, в консоле

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)